# What command in SOS windbg can dump heap for Gen 2 and LOH only?

Tags: memory, memory-leaks, windbg, heap-memory, sos

I got a high memory dump to investigate.  when I use !eeheap -gc, it gives 20 heaps, each heap has Gen 2 and LOH address info and size info.  However I want to get a overall summary of Gen 2 and LOH, and see a statistic summary on what objects are taking up memory in Gen 2 and LOH, how can I do that in windbg with SOS?  Thanks a lot for help.

!eeheap -gc

### Number of GC Heaps: 20

Heap 0 (000000293d5c4120)
generation 0 starts at 0x000000294c35d740
generation 1 starts at 0x000000294c34ceb0
generation 2 starts at 0x000000293e181000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
 segment     begin allocated  size
000000293e180000  000000293e181000  000000294c607758  0xe486758(239626072)
Large object heap starts at 0x0000002e3e181000
 segment     begin allocated  size
0000002e3e180000  0000002e3e181000  0000002e41f08640  0x3d87640(64517696)
0000002f5bc50000  0000002f5bc51000  0000002f5c190b88  0x53fb88(5503880)

### Heap Size:               Size: 0x1274d920 (309647648) bytes.

Heap 1 (000000293d5eac10)
generation 0 starts at 0x000000298b1f0440
generation 1 starts at 0x000000298b14c8c0
generation 2 starts at 0x000000297e181000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
 segment     begin allocated  size
000000297e180000  000000297e181000  000000298b5fe458  0xd47d458(222811224)
Large object heap starts at 0x0000002e42181000
 segment     begin allocated  size
0000002e42180000  0000002e42181000  0000002e43462d40  0x12e1d40(19799360)
0000002f75c50000  0000002f75c51000  0000002f787ccda8  0x2b7bda8(45596072)

### Heap Size:               Size: 0x112daf40 (288206656) bytes.

Heap 2 (000000293d611700)
generation 0 starts at 0x00000029ca38ff40
generation 1 starts at 0x00000029ca15dfd0
generation 2 starts at 0x00000029be181000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
 segment     begin allocated  size
00000029be180000  00000029be181000  00000029ca7635d0  0xc5e25d0(207496656)
Large object heap starts at 0x0000002e46181000
 segment     begin allocated  size
0000002e46180000  0000002e46181000  0000002e46e289b0  0xca79b0(13269424)
0000002fdfc50000  0000002fdfc51000  0000002fe4f2d2e0  0x52dc2e0(86885088)
0000002fa5c50000  0000002fa5c51000  0000002fa8bf5258  0x2fa4258(49955416)

### Heap Size:               Size: 0x1550a4b8 (357606584) bytes.

Heap 3 (000000293d614da0)
generation 0 starts at 0x0000002a0ce42bb8
generation 1 starts at 0x0000002a0cdac958
generation 2 starts at 0x00000029fe181000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
 segment     begin allocated  size
00000029fe180000  00000029fe181000  0000002a0cfb4bd0  0xee33bd0(249773008)
Large object heap starts at 0x0000002e4a181000
 segment     begin allocated  size
0000002e4a180000  0000002e4a181000  0000002e4dffb0b8  0x3e7a0b8(65511608)
0000002f6bc50000  0000002f6bc51000  0000002f6c09dff8  0x44cff8(4509688)

### Heap Size:               Size: 0x130fac80 (319794304) bytes.

Heap 4 (000000293d617e80)
generation 0 starts at 0x0000002a4d26e430
generation 1 starts at 0x0000002a4d0ebcd0
generation 2 starts at 0x0000002a3e181000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
 segment     begin allocated  size
0000002a3e180000  0000002a3e181000  0000002a4d2f6448  0xf175448(253187144)
Large object heap starts at 0x0000002e4e181000
 segment     begin allocated  size
0000002e4e180000  0000002e4e181000  0000002e50efad20  0x2d79d20(47684896)
0000002f57c50000  0000002f57c51000  0000002f5a4e3828  0x2892828(42543144)
0000003019c50000  0000003019c51000  000000301c929ab0  0x2cd8ab0(47024816)

### Heap Size:               Size: 0x1745a440 (390440000) bytes.

Heap 5 (0000002e9d0b9f40)
generation 0 starts at 0x0000002a8b579448
generation 1 starts at 0x0000002a8b4adb98
generation 2 starts at 0x0000002a7e181000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
 segment     begin allocated  size
0000002a7e180000  0000002a7e181000  0000002aa028f0d0  0x2210e0d0(571531472)
Large object heap starts at 0x0000002e52181000
 segment     begin allocated  size
0000002e52180000  0000002e52181000  0000002e55c4fa00  0x3acea00(61663744)
0000002f46420000  0000002f46421000  0000002f48524938  0x2103938(34617656)

### Heap Size:               Size: 0x27ce0408 (667812872) bytes.

Heap 6 (0000002e9d0df9a0)
generation 0 starts at 0x0000002aca9dc170
generation 1 starts at 0x0000002aca964f80
generation 2 starts at 0x0000002abe181000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
 segment     begin allocated  size
0000002abe180000  0000002abe181000  0000002ae0aa0050  0x2291f050(579989584)
Large object heap starts at 0x0000002e56181000
 segment     begin allocated  size
0000002e56180000  0000002e56181000  0000002e59677d00  0x34f6d00(55536896)
0000002fa9c50000  0000002fa9c51000  0000002fa9e81490  0x230490(2294928)

### Heap Size:               Size: 0x260461e0 (637821408) bytes.

Heap 7 (0000002e9d105f30)
generation 0 starts at 0x0000002b0c4fbaf0
generation 1 starts at 0x0000002b0c3da9f0
generation 2 starts at 0x0000002afe181000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
 segment     begin allocated  size
0000002afe180000  0000002afe181000  0000002b20a14f38  0x22893f38(579419960)
Large object heap starts at 0x0000002e5a181000
 segment     begin allocated  size
0000002e5a180000  0000002e5a181000  0000002e5d800950  0x367f950(57145680)
0000002f5fc50000  0000002f5fc51000  0000002f62870dc8  0x2c1fdc8(46267848)

### Heap Size:               Size: 0x28b33650 (682833488) bytes.

Heap 8 (0000002e9d12b430)
generation 0 starts at 0x0000002b4b8c6000
generation 1 starts at 0x0000002b4b8baab0
generation 2 starts at 0x0000002b3e181000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
 segment     begin allocated  size
0000002b3e180000  0000002b3e181000  0000002b659eac80  0x27869c80(663133312)
Large object heap starts at 0x0000002e5e181000
 segment     begin allocated  size
0000002e5e180000  0000002e5e181000  0000002e608d1790  0x2750790(41224080)
0000002f8fc50000  0000002f8fc51000  0000002f913efcc8  0x179ecc8(24767688)

### Heap Size:               Size: 0x2b7590d8 (729125080) bytes.

Heap 9 (0000002e9d130cc0)
generation 0 starts at 0x0000002b8e3bea38
generation 1 starts at 0x0000002b8e27c968
generation 2 starts at 0x0000002b7e181000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
 segment     begin allocated  size
0000002b7e180000  0000002b7e181000  0000002b8e404a50  0x10283a50(271071824)
Large object heap starts at 0x0000002e62181000
 segment     begin allocated  size
0000002e62180000  0000002e62181000  0000002e66069d50  0x3ee8d50(65965392)
0000002f4a420000  0000002f4a421000  0000002f4cf3e4d0  0x2b1d4d0(45208784)

### Heap Size:               Size: 0x16c89c70 (382246000) bytes.

Heap 10 (0000002e9d133f80)
generation 0 starts at 0x0000002bcd04ba08
generation 1 starts at 0x0000002bccfa8980
generation 2 starts at 0x0000002bbe181000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
 segment     begin allocated  size
0000002bbe180000  0000002bbe181000  0000002bcd220eb0  0xf09feb0(252313264)
Large object heap starts at 0x0000002e66181000
 segment     begin allocated  size
0000002e66180000  0000002e66181000  0000002e691d6a10  0x3055a10(50682384)
0000002fc9c50000  0000002fc9c51000  0000002fcc1adc78  0x255cc78(39177336)
0000002f7dc50000  0000002f7dc51000  0000002f80dc7c68  0x3176c68(51866728)

### Heap Size:               Size: 0x177c91a0 (394039712) bytes.

Heap 11 (0000002e9d136fb0)
generation 0 starts at 0x0000002c0cb208a0
generation 1 starts at 0x0000002c0c9d8c60
generation 2 starts at 0x0000002bfe181000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
 segment     begin allocated  size
0000002bfe180000  0000002bfe181000  0000002c0d542f38  0xf3c1f38(255598392)
Large object heap starts at 0x0000002e6a181000
 segment     begin allocated  size
0000002e6a180000  0000002e6a181000  0000002e6bab24f0  0x19314f0(26416368)
0000002f79c50000  0000002f79c51000  0000002f7d5d6700  0x3985700(60315392)

### Heap Size:               Size: 0x14678b28 (342330152) bytes.

Heap 12 (0000002e9d139e30)
generation 0 starts at 0x0000002c4e14ca58
generation 1 starts at 0x0000002c4e0f62f8
generation 2 starts at 0x0000002c3e181000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
 segment     begin allocated  size
0000002c3e180000  0000002c3e181000  0000002c4e27c4b8  0x100fb4b8(269464760)
Large object heap starts at 0x0000002e6e181000
 segment     begin allocated  size
0000002e6e180000  0000002e6e181000  0000002e6eac4528  0x943528(9712936)
0000002efbb90000  0000002efbb91000  0000002effaa5750  0x3f14750(66144080)
0000002fd1c50000  0000002fd1c51000  0000002fd2f887c0  0x13377c0(20150208)

### Heap Size:               Size: 0x15c8a8f0 (365471984) bytes.

Heap 13 (0000002e9d13de20)
generation 0 starts at 0x0000002c8bf4cfc0
generation 1 starts at 0x0000002c8be39ba0
generation 2 starts at 0x0000002c7e181000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
 segment     begin allocated  size
0000002c7e180000  0000002c7e181000  0000002c92e857a0  0x14d047a0(349194144)
Large object heap starts at 0x0000002e72181000
 segment     begin allocated  size
0000002e72180000  0000002e72181000  0000002e7617e498  0x3ffd498(67097752)
0000002fcdc50000  0000002fcdc51000  0000002fcf4abb08  0x185ab08(25537288)

### Heap Size:               Size: 0x1a55c740 (441829184) bytes.

Heap 14 (0000002e9d1410e0)
generation 0 starts at 0x0000002ccc867be0
generation 1 starts at 0x0000002ccc845b18
generation 2 starts at 0x0000002cbe181000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
 segment     begin allocated  size
0000002cbe180000  0000002cbe181000  0000002ccc917828  0xe796828(242837544)
Large object heap starts at 0x0000002e76181000
 segment     begin allocated  size
0000002e76180000  0000002e76181000  0000002e7973ff48  0x35bef48(56356680)
0000002f63c50000  0000002f63c51000  0000002f6762ff70  0x39def70(60682096)
0000002f9fc50000  0000002f9fc51000  0000002fa419af50  0x4549f50(72654672)

### Heap Size:               Size: 0x19c7e630 (432530992) bytes.

Heap 15 (0000002e9d144c30)
generation 0 starts at 0x0000002d0d4df148
generation 1 starts at 0x0000002d0d093900
generation 2 starts at 0x0000002cfe181000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
 segment     begin allocated  size
0000002cfe180000  0000002cfe181000  0000002d0d55d160  0xf3dc160(255705440)
Large object heap starts at 0x0000002e7a181000
 segment     begin allocated  size
0000002e7a180000  0000002e7a181000  0000002e7d4b10d8  0x33300d8(53674200)
0000002f05b90000  0000002f05b91000  0000002f08104950  0x2573950(39270736)

### Heap Size:               Size: 0x14c7fb88 (348650376) bytes.

Heap 16 (0000002e9d149fa0)
generation 0 starts at 0x0000002d4cebbc98
generation 1 starts at 0x0000002d4ce31670
generation 2 starts at 0x0000002d3e181000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
 segment     begin allocated  size
0000002d3e180000  0000002d3e181000  0000002d4cf4fac8  0xedceac8(249359048)
Large object heap starts at 0x0000002e7e181000
 segment     begin allocated  size
0000002e7e180000  0000002e7e181000  0000002e809b3508  0x2832508(42149128)
0000002f4fc50000  0000002f4fc51000  0000002f50ab68b0  0xe658b0(15095984)

### Heap Size:               Size: 0x12466880 (306604160) bytes.

Heap 17 (0000002e9d5d39b0)
generation 0 starts at 0x0000002d8eb9ffc0
generation 1 starts at 0x0000002d8eadcd88
generation 2 starts at 0x0000002d7e181000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
 segment     begin allocated  size
0000002d7e180000  0000002d7e181000  0000002d8ebebfd8  0x10a6afd8(279359448)
Large object heap starts at 0x0000002e82181000
 segment     begin allocated  size
0000002e82180000  0000002e82181000  0000002e8535c7b0  0x31db7b0(52279216)
0000002f85c50000  0000002f85c51000  0000002f8b727360  0x5ad6360(95249248)

### Heap Size:               Size: 0x1971cae8 (426887912) bytes.

Heap 18 (0000002e9d5d69c0)
generation 0 starts at 0x0000002dcc480040
generation 1 starts at 0x0000002dcc4749b8
generation 2 starts at 0x0000002dbe181000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
 segment     begin allocated  size
0000002dbe180000  0000002dbe181000  0000002dcc4da058  0xe359058(238391384)
Large object heap starts at 0x0000002e86181000
 segment     begin allocated  size
0000002e86180000  0000002e86181000  0000002e88e4a638  0x2cc9638(46962232)
0000002f53c50000  0000002f53c51000  0000002f5608e6d0  0x243d6d0(38000336)
0000002f8bc50000  0000002f8bc51000  0000002f8e3a7920  0x2756920(41249056)

### Heap Size:               Size: 0x15bb6680 (364603008) bytes.

Heap 19 (0000002e9d5d09a0)
generation 0 starts at 0x0000002e0ec60b98
generation 1 starts at 0x0000002e0ebf5790
generation 2 starts at 0x0000002dfe181000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
 segment     begin allocated  size
0000002dfe180000  0000002dfe181000  0000002e0ecc09c8  0x10b3f9c8(280230344)
Large object heap starts at 0x0000002e8a181000
 segment     begin allocated  size
0000002e8a180000  0000002e8a181000  0000002e8ccc84f0  0x2b474f0(45380848)
0000002f6fc50000  0000002f6fc51000  0000002f706390c0  0x9e80c0(10387648)

### Heap Size:               Size: 0x1406ef78 (335998840) bytes.

GC Heap Size:            Size: 0x1fc193f68 (8524480360) bytes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`!sosex.dumpgen 2` or `!dumpgen 3` will do the trick. Gen3 is obviously a misnomer, but it was an easy way to do the LOH. Alternatively, you can call `!sosex.dumpgen loh`. I believe that !sos.dumpheap now has a param for generation as well.

Comment: Thanks Steve, sorry for follow up question,  I type

Comment: Thanks Steven, I tried this  :000> !dumpgen 3
No export dumpgen found
 I can confirm that sos is loaded, but dumpgen is not recognized.  is there any prereq I need do before hand?  Thanks

Comment: @SkyLine: Steve Johnson is the author of [tag:sosex] <-- read the tag info

Comment: awesome :)  I find an instruction and get sosex works, it's great,  curious, does anyone know how to look it up by using sos only?  our debug env does not have sosex built in by default

Comment: It works great, thank you @Steve Johnson and Thomas Weller

Comment: Just what I was looking for. My last 10 windbg questions have been answered by comments from Steve Johnson and @Thomas Weller (posted over the course of the last many years). Thank you guys!! :-)

Comment: @JeffreyLeCours: I'm glad I could help and give back to the community from which I have learned so much. WinDbg is good, but not exactly self-explaining.